# ASP.NET ASMXのサービスを参照使用する際のURLの変更の仕方

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

ASP.NETでASMXでウェブAPIを作成します。
これをC#のプロジェクトから参照設定して関数呼び出しのような形で使用できますが、
参照設定する際にURLを指定する必要がありますよね。

このURL指定は参照設定の際にしなければならないのでしょうか？
本番環境ではURLが違うので、できれば設定ファイルなどから取得してプログラミングをしたいと思っています。
やり方がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたらお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

Webサービスの参照方法には二種類がありますが、どちらも既定で設定ファイルによりエンドポイントを変更することができます。

より新しい「サービス参照」を使用した場合は、app.configの`system.serviceModel`セクションの`endpoint`で変更します。詳しく知りたければWCFについて調べてください。

[image: サービス参照の設定]

またWeb参照の場合はSettings.settingsに項目が追加されますので、app.configの`applicationSettings`もしくはプロジェクトのプロパティから変更を行ってください。

[image: Web参照の設定]